# Change language of site with a html button

Tags: php, html, variables, button

In PHP, I want to change the language (English, German, etc) of the site when clicking a button.  Is this the right way to approach that problem?

```
<?php 
  $language;
  if ($language == "en") {
    include("headerEn.php");
  } else {
    include("header.php");
  } 
?>
<a href="index.php"><?php $language = "en"; ?>
<img src="images/language/languageNO.png"></a>

<a href="index.php"><?php $language = "no"; ?>
<img src="images/language/languageEN.png"></a>
```

What is the best way to change the language of the site and have it persist when the user returns?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can do this by

```
<a href="index.php?language=en">
<a href="index.php?language=no">
```

and get the languages and store them in cookie and include file according to cookie like

```
if ( !empty($_GET['language']) ) {
    $_COOKIE['language'] = $_GET['language'] === 'en' ? 'en' : 'nl';
} else {
    $_COOKIE['language'] = 'nl';
}
setcookie('language', $_COOKIE['language']);
```

and than

```
if ( $_COOKIE['language'] == "en") {
   include("headerEn.php");
} else {
   include("header.php");
} ?>
```

Comment: I think the else part should be `else if (empty($_COOKIE['language']))`, to avoid resetting the language to 'nl' when the cookie (and not the request) contains the choosen language.

Answer (score 3):

To give a solution without changing your approach, You can do like this.

```
<?php 
if(isset($_GET['language']))
  $language = $_GET['language'];
else
  $language = "";

if ($language == "en") {
   include("headerEn.php");
} else {
   include("header.php");
} ?>

<a href="index.php?language = en"><img src="images/language/languageNO.png">      </a>
<a href="index.php?language = no"><img src="images/language/languageEN.png"></a>
```

If you want to keep the selection, you can store this value in **Database or Session.**

Answer (score 3):

It is always good to have a default value, so that you never end up being in a no-language site.

```
$language = $_REQUEST["language"];
$default_header="myheaderXXX.php";

switch ($language) {
    case "en":
      include("headerEn.php");
      break;

    case "no":
      include("header.php");
      break;

    default:
      include($default_header);
}
```

And then create links like this:

```
<a href="index.php?language=en">
<a href="index.php?language=no">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to save this `$language` value to **session** variable. When the page reloaded check that the session variable is set or not.

If set use that `$language`

NOTE:

```
$language = $_GET['language'];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't change a variable within PHP by html. PHP is serversided HTML is clientsided

You can use [GET variables](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_get.asp) to change it though. It is the easiest way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the same code like this . I have editted your code .

```
<?php 
$language; ?>
<?php if ($language == "en") : ?>
    <?php include("headerEn.php"); ?>
     <a href="index.php"><?php $language = "en"; ?><img src="images/language/languageNO.png"></a> 
<?php else: ?>
    <?php include("header.php"); ?>
     <a href="index.php"><?php $language = "no"; ?><img src="images/language/languageEN.png"></a>
<?php endif; ?>
```

this will solve your problem .

Answer (score 0):

In this case I have tried use Session variables to store and define language. Every thing works until i turn on caching. When caching was enabled even reload page returns same language and user could not change language.
So I consider to change language using AJAX request after clicking on language button (national flag)