# Staying at the current page when switching language in PHP

Tags: php, html

I want the user can switch languages without changing the current page by clicking the language link.

I found a code like the one below. It works but cannot find the page because the page names are different. For example: When I change the language while on "**../en/about.php**" page, it goes to "**../tr/about.php**" page. The page that should go is "**../tr/hakkimizda.php**".

How can I solve this problem?

```
    <?php
//URL path. eg: index-en/job.php
$path = trim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'],'/');

//language from URL. eg: index-en
$lang = explode('/',$path)[0];

//Paths in other languages: eg: 'tr' => 'index-cn/job.php'
$langs = [
    'en'=>preg_replace("/$lang/",'../en',$path,1),
    'tr'=>preg_replace("/$lang/",'../tr',$path,1),
];
?>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li>
       <a href="<?= $langs['tr']?>">Türkçe</a>
    </li>
    <li>
       <a href="<?= $langs['en']?>">English</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have to define that `about` should redirect to `hakkimizda`. The code does what it's supposed to, change `en/something` to `tr/something`.

Comment: How can i do that? I don't know php language

Comment: look at this question [Change language of site with a html button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068132/change-language-of-site-with-a-html-button)

Comment: I looked at link but it didn't help me.

Comment: use: 
     $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know php language but I solved the problem with javascript.

Solution:

```
<a class="nav-link" href="#" id="LangRedirect">English</a>
```

JavaScript

```
$("#LangRedirect").click(function LangRedirect(){
var lang,en,tr;
    lang=window.location.pathname;
    en="/en/";
    tr="/tr/";
switch (lang){
     // About
    case en+"about.php": location.assign(tr+"hakkimizda.php");
    break;
    case tr+"hakkimizda.php": location.assign(en+"about.php");
    break;
    default: window.location.pathname=(en+"404.php");
}});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use global `arrays` for each language and search `current path` into the corresponding array when you should get the `key` of this path. Then you can use the array for another language to search the path for this `key`, for example, you have:

```
$EN = array('about' => 'about.php');
$TR = array('about' => 'hakkimizda.php');
```

FIRST:

search the `key` for `'about.php'` in the array `$EN`;

THEN:

use this `key` (which would be `about`) to search corresponding entry in the `$TR`.

I suggest, that these arrays should be `global`

Comment: Thank you for answer. But how can i do that? I don't know php language :(